# FixedThreadPool not parallel enough

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, executorservice

I create a fixed threadpool using `forPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);` where poolSize is initialized to the number of cores on the processor (lets say 4). In some runs, it works fine and the CPU utilisation is consistently at 400%.

But sometimes, the usage drops to 100%, and never rises back to 400%. I have 1000s of tasks scheduled, so the problem is not that. I catch every exception, but no exception is thrown. So the issue is random and not reproducible, but very much present. They are data parallel operations. At the end of each thread, there is a synchronised access to update a single variable. Highly unlikely I have a deadlock there. In fact, once I spot this issue, if I destroy the pool, and create a fresh one of size 4, it is still only 100% usage. There is no I/O.

It seems counter intuitive to java's assurance of a "FixedThreadPool". Am I reading the guarantee wrong? Is only concurrency guaranteed and not parallelism?

And to the question - Have you come across this issue and solved it? If I want parallelism, am I doing the correct thing?

Thanks!

On doing a thread dump:
I find that there are 4 threads all doing their parallel operations. But the usage is still ~100% only. Here are the thread dumps at [400% usage](http://pastebin.com/KwVVmQs1) and [100% usage](http://pastebin.com/DviSQZWW). I set the number of threads to 16 to trigger the scenario. It runs at 400% for a while, and then drops to 100%. When I use 4 threads, it runs on 400% and only rarely drops to 100%. [This](https://github.com/sancha/jrae/blob/master/src/parallel/Parallel.java) is the parallelization code.

******** *[MAJOR UPDATE]* **********

It turns out that if I give the JVM a huge amount of memory to play with, this issue is solved  and the performance does not drop. But I don't know how to use this information to solve this issue. Help!

Comment: Have you taken a thread dump of your program during the 'problem phase'?

Comment: @Sanjeev Does your tasks use any kind of synchronization? Because we have first to assume that your tasks can be entirely runnable in paralell. Is that what you are implying?

Comment: What is  the task performed - does it have IO?  You can capture thread dumps when it is at 100% and see what the four threads of the pool are doing.

Comment: 1. I have taken a thread dump. You are suggesting that it could be one of my threads misbehaving?
2. They are data parallel operations. At the end of each thread, there is a synchronised access to update a single variable. Highly unlikely I have a deadlock there. In fact, once I spot this issue, if I destroy the pool, and create a fresh one of size 4, it is still only 100% usage.
3. It does not have I/O. Ah! Ok, I will definitely try that. Thanks

Comment: @all, fixedThreadPools do guarantee parallelism, right?

Comment: no no, I am sorry, I said I have *not* taken a thread dump. But the editor wouldn't allow it because I can't edit it more than once in 5 minutes.

Comment: I am trying to do that, but I can't invoke the scenario now. I will and post results immediately.

Comment: Done. No help though, all threads are active, but usage is still ~100% only!

Comment: '~100%' is very suspicious.  Is it ever over 100%, if only by a bit, eg. '101%'?  It's like your CPU utilization is being normalized.  What does 'mpstat -P ALL' say about usage by CPU?

Comment: Yes, it runs over 100% for a couple of seconds.

Comment: I noticed one difference between the 400% thread dump and the 100% thread dump. In the 100% thread dump, there are at least 2 threads on this line:  at org.jblas.DoubleMatrix.<init>(DoubleMatrix.java:321), which means they seem to be busy allocating memory. In the 400% thread dump, no threads were on this line. Perhaps the JVM is busy allocating more heap space when you have it set to use less memory. Maybe you can print out memory settings periodically. (See the Runtime class for different memory state you can view.)

Comment: Here is a MemoryInfo class you can use to log memory statistics while processing: http://pastebin.com/Mpw3b3yy

Comment: i am amazed noone asked yet...but can u pls provide the system spec like cpu/core count as well as physical memory size and the memory you are specifying for the jvm? And if possible small snippet of the code to figure out are you allocating too many objects?

Comment: I have access to machines from 4GB to 48GB ram, accordingly I give the JVM ~90% memory on the machines. The core count is 8 almost always. Checkout line 57 here https://github.com/sancha/jrae/blob/master/src/rae/RAEFeatureExtractor.java for usage.

Comment: Could you reran the tests with the JVM flag `-XX:-UseTLAB`? See my answer for details.

Comment: @Sanjeev Satheesh Have you profiled the GC?  When you have the program running with the lower amount of memory how much of it was regularly GC'd?

Comment: @MichaelSchmeißer I tried running with -UseTLAB, that didn't help :(

Comment: @JohnVint The GC doesn't seem to free as much memory as I expect it to. The best hypothesis I have now is that some of the memory is still referenced, although I cannot find any clear locations where this is happening.

Comment: Could you please add the JVM version?

Comment: @MichaelSchmeißer java version "1.6.0_27"      
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_27-b07)         
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.2-b06, mixed mode)

Comment: @SanjeevSatheesh were you able to figure out what was going on?

Answer (score 5):

Given the fact that increasing your heap size makes the problem 'go away' (perhaps not permanently), the issue is probably related to GC.

Is it possible that the Operation implementation is generating some state, that is stored on the heap, between calls to

```
pOperation.perform(...);
```

?  If so, then you might have a memory usage problem, perhaps a leak.  As more tasks complete, more data is on the heap.  The garbage collector has to work harder and harder to try and reclaim as much as it can, gradually taking up 75% of your total available CPU resources.  Even destroying the ThreadPool won't help, because that's not where the references are stored, it's in the Operation.

The 16 thread case hitting this problem more could be due to the fact that it's generating more state quicker (don't know the Operation implementation, so hard for me to say).

And increasing the heap size while keeping the problem set the same would make this problem appear to disappear, because you'd have more room for all this state.

Comment: That is what I think also. If the memory usage keeps growing then there is a memory leak for sure, but I can't seem to pinpoint it myself - All the references get reinitialized, and explicitly calling the gc doesn't reduce memory usage either :(

Comment: Seems to me there's two possibilities: one is that you've got a memory usage problem related to the keeping of the results of Operation.perform(), the other is more like a leak.  To figure out which, I'd changer perform() so that the results are not stored in memory: just throw them out for the purposes of your test.  If that doesn't solve the problem, then assume a leak:  continue dropping the results, run this test under a profiler (I like JProfiler, but whatever), and see where your memory is going.  That should narrow it down, unless the problem is in native code.

Comment: @SanjeevSatheesh sorry, forgot to reference you in my comment.

Comment: It is the latter case, that there is a memory leak. I tried profiling, but because of the large amount of data, eclipse dies :/ So the profiling route didn't work out. From whatever I got out of the profiler, the largest amount of memory were from small matrices that I was creating but they are all shortlived ~1s. So I am back to square one.

Comment: @SanjeevSatheesh It's not going to be trivial to find this, but some points of advice:  1) if you think Eclipse is causing you trouble, take it out of the picture.  Most profiling tools will work on compiled code, you don't HAVE to use the IDE debugger.  2) Because you can reliably reproduce the problem, this is amenable to brute force tracking down.  Just keep removing functionality from .perform().  3) If you've got enough short-lived, relatively big objects you may really have a tuning problem.  Start here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest that you use the [Yourkit Thread Analysis](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/80/help/threads.jsp) feature to understand the real behavior. It will tell you exactly which threads are running, blocked or waiting and why.

If you can't/don't want to purchase it, next best option is to use [Visual VM](http://visualvm.java.net/features.html), which is bundled with the JDK to do this analysis. It won't give you as detailed information as Yourkit. Following blog post can get you started with Visual VM:
http://marxsoftware.blogspot.in/2009/06/thread-analysis-with-visualvm.html

Comment: let me take a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: BTW You can get a short term evaluation license for YourKit, so you don't have to buy it to try it. ;)

Answer (score 2):

My answer is based on a mixture of knowledge about JVM memory management and some guesses about facts which I could not find precise information on. I believe that your problem is related to the thread-local allocation buffers (TLABs) Java uses:

> A Thread Local Allocation Buffer (TLAB) is a region of Eden that is
>   used for allocation by a single thread. It enables a thread to do
>   object allocation using thread local top and limit pointers, which is
>   faster than doing an atomic operation on a top pointer that is shared
>   across threads.

Let's say you have an eden size of 2M and use 4 threads: The JVM may choose a TLAB size of (eden/64)=32K and each thread gets a TLAB of that size. Once the 32K TLAB of a thread are exhausted, it needs to acquire a new one, which requires global synchronization. Global synchronization is also needed for allocation of objects which are larger than the TLAB.

But, to be honest with you, things are not as easy as I described: The JVM adaptively sizes a thread's TLAB based on its estimated allocation rate determined at minor GCs [[1](https://blogs.oracle.com/daviddetlefs/entry/tlab_sizing_an_annoying_little)] which makes TLAB-related behavior even less predictable. However, I can imagine that the JVM scales the TLAB sizes down when more threads are working. This seems to make sense, because the sum of all TLABs must be less than the available eden space (and even some fraction of the eden space in practice to be able to refill the TLABs).

Let us assume a fixed TLAB size per thread of (eden size / (16 * user threads working)):

- for 4 threads this results in TLABs of 32K
- for 16 threads this results in TLABs of 8K

You can imagine that 16 threads which exhaust their TLAB faster because it's smaller will cause much more locks on the TLAB allocator than 4 threads with 32K TLABs.

To conclude, when you decrease the number of working threads or increase the memory available to the JVM, the threads can be given larger TLABs and the problem is solved.

https://blogs.oracle.com/daviddetlefs/entry/tlab_sizing_an_annoying_little

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly due to GC.

If you want to be sure add the following startup flags to your Java program: 
`-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps`
and check stdout.

You will see lines containing "Full GC" including the time this took: during this time you will see 100% CPU usage.

The default garbage collector on multi-CPU or multi-core machines is the throughput collector, which collects the young generation in parallel but uses serial collection (in one thread) for the old generation.

So what is probably happening is that in your 100% CPU example, GC is going on of the old generation which is done in one thread and so keeps one core busy only.

Suggestion for solution: use the concurrent mark-and-sweep collector, by using the flag 
 `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` at JVM startup.

Answer (score 0):

A total cpu utilisation at a 100% implied that you have written is single threaded. i.e. you may have any number of concurrent tasks, but due to locking, only one can execute at a time.

If you have high IO you can get less than 400% but it is unlikely you will get a round number of cpu utilisation. e.g. you might see 38%, 259%, 72%, 9% etc. (It is also likely to jump around)

A common problem is locking the data you are using too often. You need to consider how it could be re-written where locking is performed for the briefest period and smallest portion of the overall work. Ideally, you want to avoid locking all together.

Using multiple thread means you can use up to that many cpus, but if your code prevents it you are likely to be better off (i.e. faster) to write the code single threaded as it avoids the overhead of locking.

Comment: There is no I/O, and the locking is almost trivial. Like I said, on doing a thread dump at this stage, all threads are present and doing their independent operations - this slowdown in not due to blocking.

Comment: You can't say its not due to blocking until you know what it is. Can you show use the thread dump of the four threads doing their thing?

Comment: Each thread is processing heavy, and the only synchronised part is the update of a single variable around which I have an acquire and release lock. On doing the thread dump, I find that all of them are in the middle of the their processing routines and not blocking on this lock. I could post the dump somewhere if you'd like.

Comment: In the question as a code block would be good. Just the four threads when its uses 100% instead of 400%.

Comment: done! I had to use 16 threads to trigger the scenario, so it was too much to post as a quote, so I put them on pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using locking, it is possible that one of your four threads attains the lock but is then context switched - perhaps to run the GC thread. The other threads can't make progress since they can't attain the lock. When the thread context switches back, it completes the work in the critical section and relinquishes the lock to allow only one other thread to attain the lock. So now you have two threads active. It is possible that while the second thread executes the critical section the first thread does the next piece of data parallel work but generates enough garbage to trigger the GC and we're back where we started :)

P.S. This is just a best guess since it is hard to figure out what is happenning without any code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the size of the Java heap usually improves throughput until the heap no longer resides in physical memory. When the heap size exceeds the physical memory, the heap begins swapping to disk which causes Java performance to drastically decrease. Therefore, it is important to set the maximum heap size to a value that allows the heap to be contained within physical memory.

Since you give the JVM ~90% of physical memory on the machines, problem may be related to IO happening due to memory paging and swapping when you try to allocate memory for more objects. Note that the physical memory is also used by other running processes as well as OS. Also since symptoms occur after a while, this is also indication for memory leaks.

> Try to find out how much physical memory is available (not already
>   used) and allocate ~90% of available physical memory to your JVM heap.

- What happens if you leave the system running for extended period of
  time?
- Does it ever comes back at CPU 400% of utilization?
- Do you notice any disk activity when CPU is at 100% of utilization?
- Can you monitor which threads are running and which are blocked and
  when?

Take a look at following link for tuning:
http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/tuning.html#section4